# Forms Authentication & ASP.NET Membership Session Timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication, session-timeout

I have a website which has **Forms Authentication** and **ASP.NET Membership** is used in it. At some pages **Transactions** (System.Transactions) are used too.

After deploying it to the server, the session timeout issue is creating a mess, and few E-mail relays and DB operations are unable to be executed.

I want to know how can I fix this issue. If additional information is needed I can provide.

I have looked into too many blogs and forums, but could not find the solution or the correct/single solution.

Following error is shown sometimes:-
**Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.**

And the application is deployed on **Windows 2008 R2 Server** with **IIS 7.5**.

Looking forward for quick response.

Comment: The error message makes me believe the timeout has to do with a database connection. That means it has nothing to do with Forms Authentication. But without more information, it's difficult to help. Could you post the code that is throwing the exception at least?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're not closing your DB connections correctly.

Make sure any place you open a SQL connection that you're closing it. Ideally wrap them in using blocks.

Post up some some of your typical DB code and I'll review it.

Comment: Yes DaveHogan, your guess seems to be quite near to the problem, I will look into the DB Connections and close them wherever needed. Because once I closed the connections myself, since few other developers have worked on this website project therefore some connections were not properly closed/disposed.